# Image in anychart doesn't fix the stage

Tags: image, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm trying to put some logos in a chart for print them, but depending of the screen resolution logo at the right sometimes is out of the chart area and sometimes is far of the edge. I'm using stage and putting the logo with `graphics.image`. This is the code anychart v 8.2.1

```
var image = anychart.graphics.image("logo_mues2020.png", "12%", "9%",102, 43);
image.parent(container);
image = anychart.graphics.image("gepp2020.jpg", "72%", "9%", 155, 47);          
image.parent(container);
```

container is a stage

And these are the examples in two different devices
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5741/tmDgQA.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/7563/QuQJcI.png

does somebody has made something similar?
is there a way to fix it with the chart area or make it fit more better and really responsive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the image size is applied in pixels, not percents. it means that the image is not resized along with the container and when the container has a small width the image goes beyond the chart.
To solve that you should use percents for the image size and apply the align setting. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/O7sMUTce/1) and pay attention to lines 17 and 19.
Try to resize the chart view to see how it works.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I'm gonna try it. I only have a question whats does line 19 do?
`image.align('x-mid-y-mid');`

Comment: It applies the image scaling. You can learn more about it at the following page - https://api.anychart.com/anychart.graphics.vector.Image.Align

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you so much